# PHP Replacing Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

Im creating an array of products, each with an ID and score:

```
$savedProducts = array( 'product' => array("product_id" => $product_id,"product_score" => $score));
```

I want to be able to update the score by using the product_id as identifier.

I've tried:

```
foreach($savedProducts as $key => $val)
{

    if ($val == $property_id )
    {                   
        $savedProducts[$key] = $score;
        break;
    }
}
```

Which keeps adding a new array item, rather than updating the original.

I think the issue is that my initial array setup then doesn't match the edited one.

Initial array:

```
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 125026
            [product_score] => 5
        )

)
```

After trying to update score:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 125026
                    [product_score] => 4
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [product_id] => 125026
                            [product_score] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So it keeps addding elements, rather than updating the existing.

Comment: How does `$savedProperties` look like?

Comment: With this array structure you can only have one 'product' because new added entries will override the key?! Or is 'product' just a placeholder for something else?

Comment: You seem to have a savedProducts and a savedProperties, I presume they should be the same. Which would make changing your array a lot easier :-)

Answer (score 1):

with PHP 5.5 use:

```
$savedProducts = array_column($savedProducts, NULL, 'product_id');
```

then you can access your product with:

```
$savedProducts[$product_id]
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 125026 (where the number is my product_id) , thats on PHP5.5.7

Comment: can you `print_r` your `$savedProducts` and append it to your question

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
foreach($savedProducts as $key => $val)
{
if($val['product_id'] == $property_id)
{                   
    $savedProperties[$key]['product_score'] = $score;
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: I then get Notice: Undefined index: product_id